# GET Magento2 category product images

Tags: magento2, product, category, image

How to get product images of a specific category in magento2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code might help you.

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
protected $_categoryFactory;
protected $_imageHelper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
) {
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->__imageHelper = $imageHelper;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $categoryId = 'yourcategoryid';
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    return $collection;
}

public function getImageUrl(){
    $collection = $this->getProductCollection();

    foreach ($collection as $product){

        // small image 
        echo $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->getUrl();

        // medium image 
        echo $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium')->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->getUrl();

        // large image 
        echo $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_large')->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->getUrl();


    }

}
```

PS: I haven't tested it but it should work as per my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how to load the images of category in phtml file

Comment: iam getting only one category image of product

Comment: create a function in block and load category and return image url using : 
 $categoryId = 'yourcategoryid';
 $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
return $category->getImageUrl();

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will check it and  get back to you

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it is working for you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi,     public function getImages(){

      $categoryId = '218'; 
      $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId); 
 
      foreach ($collection as $product){
      $imageurl=$this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->getUrl();
      }
      return $imageurl; 
    }

Comment: i have created function like above but still iam getting only one image

Comment: write $imageurl[] = $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->getUrl();  instead of only $image variable.